# How do I show "Open With" dialog on OS X for unknown file type?

Tags: java, macos

In my Java application that runs on OS X I need to open the document that has an extension that is not associated with any application. I need to display the standard OS X 'Open With' dialog, so the user can select the application.

[image]

What command do I use to show this dialog?

Comment: Try to execute a command to [open a file](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25844/can-i-open-files-in-textedit-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x) from your java code. You can execute external commands via [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/).